# How to compare two dates from db in CI

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to compare two date which is stored in database.and for this,i have write a query like this.

```
 $rs = $this->db->select('jb_emp.*')
                    ->from('jb_emp')
                    ->where('jb_emp.employer_id',$id)
                    ->where('jb_emp.status','Active')
                    ->where('jb_emp.save_draft',NULL)
                    ->where('date(jb_emp.create_date)<=','date(jb_emp.start_date)')
                    ->where('date(jb_emp.end_date) > ', date('Y-m-d h:m:s'))
                    ->get()->result_array();
                    echo "<pre>" ;print_r($rs);die();
```

According to query, i should get the data where create date is less than start date,but i'm getting just opposite to it(where create date is greater than to start date)and if i uses greater than sign instead of less than,i don't get any data.

Here i just want to access the data where create date is less than or equal to start date.

Can anyone help me to get this? Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Pls show us some sample data where you think you are getting incorrect results. My bet is that you store dates as a string with English or American date formatting. The only way we can really help if we can see your data.

Comment: whats `start_date` and `create_date`. explain this

Comment: start_date and create_date are two fields of a table in db.and suppose start_date is  2018-02-27 and create_date is 2018-02-17 or both are equal then i want to display the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example only

```
public function index() {

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r$this->yourfunctionname(1);
    echo "</pre>";
}

public function yourfunctionname($id) {
    $this->db->where('employer_id',$id);
    $this->db->where('status','Active');
    $this->db->where('save_draft',NULL);
    $this->db->where('date(create_date) <=', 'date(start_date)');
    $this->db->where('date(end_date) >', date('Y-m-d h:m:s'));

    $query = $this->db->get('jb_emp');

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: same issue i have with this query as i have posted here